# 403 Forbidden - ONLY from my computer

Tags: http-status-code-403

Problem: when I visit particular url the site goes white and the title of the tab says "403 Forbidden" and nothing else happens.

I wanted to ask the forumees here about this weird problem when I, and I solely, cannot access one particular website, until I've run right into very same problem with yet another site just now.

Apparently the problem lies with my computer, and my computer only.
The site IS accessible by everyone except of me.

I cleaned the cache, removed all sh!t files, restarted the modem and the computer couple of times already, to no avail.
I can access those sites via my phone, I can access them from anywhere else but! my computer.

Has anyone stumbled upon such a problem?

Comment: MINUS? And this because of.... ? That I dared to ASK a question?

Comment: I think the downvotes are because this is not a programing question.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of reasons behind this. Your browser, a browser extension, IP address shitlisted for some reason (usually spamming), some sort of virus that gets detected by remote antiviruses and block your connections, some adware or spyware that rewrites your requests...

It's also possible that if you only have problems with those two websites and especially if you did something you were not supposed to, maybe they just blocked you out.

So try using a proxy server or a VPN like strongvpn. If it works then at least you know it's got something to do with your IP address.

Comment: I tried to use different IP, to no avail ( through FF plugin ). Using very same modem ( wireless ) and still on the same IP I can access the site via my mobile. My desktop is blocked, though.

Comment: Try using another browser then. Give the computer a virus scan.

Comment: I triad connecting via all of the browsers I have installed ( 5 ). Virus scan didn't find anything, and I am using F-Secure

Comment: If you can connect from the mobile using the same IP address but not from the computer, then it's definitely something wrong with the computer or browser. Try removing all browser extensions, clear the cache, cookies, restart the browsers. Disable the antivirus and try again without it as well. Check for adware/spyware that might rewrite or redirect or mangle your browser requests - not all are found by antiviruses.

Comment: I realize the problem lies solely with my computer and nowhere else. How to fix it - this question remains.

Comment: Steps I have taken so far: restarted the modem, restarted (!) my machine, cleared all the cache etc. I tried to open the site with one browser I never used (on this very page, that is) so I knew there are no cookies or other stuff of that kind. Result? Nothing. Seems like my computer itself, its name, is being blocked. 

I wanted to confirm that with the hosting provider, there're bunch of idiots claiming I was stupid and the problem lies with me, not them. I KNOW the problem lies with my machine but they refused to investigate further on this matter.

Comment: Then reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Little update: seems not only this ONE webpage is being blocked; I received same error on bunch of other websites. What I've found out: I did the testing while restarting the system over and over again and typing in TWO web addresses that normally are blocked. 
--------------------
When the system’s booted and I open Chrome or FF or both, I CAN SEE those pages. Then, when rest of the programs are loaded in in the background - the 403 error jumps in and I no longer can see the sites. I noticed this is related to the Network (I am on Win 7):

Comment: when the network is still processing its booting (the bottom right ‘screen’ icon has a loading image on it) the sites are available. When the icon becomes solid, the sites get 403 error. Maybe coincidence, not sure yet.
--------------------
Is there a way to see what program is causing what? I mean, like to see what’s woken up my computer I can type bunch of commands in CMD mode. Is there something like that available that would tell me WHAT app or program is causing 403 forbidden error on my computer?

Comment: It could be an application on your computer, like a browser plugin, a trojan or some sort of proxy or antivirus or adware, or it can be something else like a transparent proxy at your provider that kicks in after some delay, there are really so many things that could mess up... try looking at your process list and see if you have anything you don't recognize. I think you'll be better off reinstalling your windows, then an antivirus and then Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. One solution is to open a PRIVATE tab, it worked for me. And to fix that issue without going to a private tab, I went to the developer console, then Application tab, then cleared all cookies for the domain, then refresh and it worked.